# can I execute code inside a popup when it is being closed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

in my chrome extension I want the popup whenever it is being closed to send a message to the background script. This message should contain the current content of a text area on the popup as well as the url of the tab the popup was opened on.

```
window.onblur = function(){
    let text = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: text});
}
```

With just the content of the text area everything works fine. However when i want to add the url of the current tab like this:

```
window.onblur = function(){
    let text = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        let currentTab = tabs[0].url;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: text; url: currentTab});
    });
}
```

nothing is received by the background script before the popup is closed. I'm guessing this is just because it takes too long right? Is there a way I could make this work? It is important that I really get the url of the tab the popup was opened on. When I for example move the query to the background script and close the popup by switching tabs the url of the new tab is being printed out instead of the one I want.

Thank you :)

Comment: Grab the current tab's information when the popup is opened and store it in a variable. Then, when it is closed, send that variable to background script along with the textarea information.

Comment: Thank you, but would that also work if there's two chrome windows each with the popup open? Wouldn't the second one overwrite the first?

Comment: Each popup window is an independent instance. Each one will have their own local variables.

Comment: Okay thank you very much :) But why does the debug console of the one chrome window also print the console.log() of the background script of the second chrome window? That's what confused me...